# Conditions in MySQL case

Tags: mysql

I have simple procedure, which should return 1, when another table has rows and 0 when it hasn't.

```
BEGIN
DECLARE var INT;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable INTO var;
    CASE var WHEN var > 0 THEN
        SELECT 1 as NUMBER;
    WHEN var = 0 THEN
        SELECT 0 as NUMBER;
    END CASE;
END
```

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable` - Query returns 0, but procedure returns 1, CAST(var as UNSIGNED) doesn't work. How to repair this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing [`CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) forms. Remove `var` from `CASE var`, or remove `var` from your conditions.

The way you're doing it, when `var = 0`, you're comparing `var (0)` with `var > 0 (0)`, which matches, so selects `1`.

Here, I've taken `var` out of the `CASE` clause but left it in the `WHEN` clauses:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE var INT;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable INTO var;
    CASE WHEN var > 0 THEN
        SELECT 1 as NUMBER;
    WHEN var = 0 THEN
        SELECT 0 as NUMBER;
    END CASE;
END
```